Join two tables, T1 with distinct IDs and T2 with duplicate IDs, and create column indicating if code from T2 is associated with ID
I have two tables. Table 1 has distinct IDs
Table 1:



ID




123


456


789



*Note: There are more columns in T1 but not shown for clarity
Table 2 has multiple codes associated with each ID. It looks like this:



ID
Code




123
001


123
002


123
003


123
004


456
001


456
003


789
002


789
003



I need to join T2 onto T1 and I need to create a column of labels where if a ID is associated with code 002 or 004 then it should be labeled DISCHARGED. If not associated then OTHER
My output should look like this:



ID
Label




123
DISCHARGED


456
OTHER


789
DISCHARGED



I tried this SQL
SELECT t1.ID,
    CASE
        WHEN t2.CODE IN ('002','004') THEN 'DISCHARGED'
        ELSE 'OTHER'
    END AS LABEL
FROM T1.t1
LEFT JOIN T2.t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID 
GROUP BY    
    CASE
        WHEN t2.CODE IN ('002','004') THEN 'DISCHARGED'
        ELSE 'OTHER'
    END, 
    t1.ID

But this is giving me duplicate IDs and therefore way too many rows
EDIT: The IDs that I am working with are actually numbers (column type NUMBER(22). I used letters for simplicity but I realized it may effect the answers so I am changing the IDs.

To make things clearer, add one column to the T1 sample data. (Have you simplified too much?)

Hint: MIN() aggregate function.

The column name ID implies it's a unique column. Please change the column name since it could be confusing.

What do you want to do if a given ID falls in 2 buckets?  For example, ID A will be in both discharged and other.  (the min() hint is relevant here....)

SELECT t1.id,
    CASE WHEN max(CASE WHEN t2.code IN ('002', '004') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN 'Discharged' ELSE 'Other' END AS Label
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id


This code try to solve the problem with CTE, left join and ISNULL.
this run in SQL Server
Query
with T1_Labeled as (
    SELECT MIN(ID) as ID, 'DISCHARGED' as Label
    from T2
    where T2.CODE IN ('002','004')
    Group by ID
)
SELECT T1.ID, ISNULL(Label,'OTHER') Label
from T1
left join T1_Labeled
on T1.ID = T1_Labeled.ID;

Output
ID  Label
A   DISCHARGED
B   OTHER
C   DISCHARGED

Schema
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T1](
    [ID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T2](
    [ID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](3) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

